# path from model view controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I allow myself to ask you a question today, because I have a small problem in my code. my links are not yet dynamic and I would like to make them dynamic so that they can show me certain resources. My action is supposed to direct me to my episode page but it can't find it. I have an mvc model. my problem is: **"href="./?action="episode?idE=**" Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?php
include 'modele/connexionBD.php';

$req = "SELECT nomA, imageA, episode.*  FROM episode, anime WHERE episode.idA = anime.idA AND idAcE";
$res = $conn->query($req);
$animes = $res->fetchAll();
?>

<section class="hero-section">
    <div class="container-fluid ctn-card">
        <?php
        foreach ($animes as $anime) {
        ?>
            <a class="card" href="./?action=episode?idE=<?php echo $anime['idE']; ?>">
                <div class="card__background" style="background-image: url(./image/<?php echo $anime['imageA'] ?>)"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid ctn-content">
                    <span class="card__category">Episode <?php echo $anime['numE'] ?></span>
                    <h3 class="card__heading"><?php echo $anime['nomA'] ?></h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I assume you're talking about what happens when you click the link at the beginning of this code snippet? Is there a specific problem or error you encounter when you do that? And where is the code which processes that request? If there's an issue, it's potentially in there (unless of course the code you've shown us is generating the wrong URL or something). We need more clarity about what precisely goes wrong, and you need to ensure you've provided a [mre] of the issue including relevant code and data.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that doesn't really clarify much. Review my comment above and try to provide the specific detail which I requested.

Comment: I think I'm clear, my only problem here is my action which does not lead to the requested page which is "episode".

Comment: `does not lead to`...yes we understand that. The question is, what does it do instead? Do you see an error, or other unexpected result? Knowing what it _does_ do is far more useful for diagnosing the problem that what it doesn't do. And also, have you done any debugging? Is the URL it's accessing the one you expect it to use? And if so, why do you expect it to work? Have you looked at the MVC routing code to see what it ought to do, or tried to debug the path it takes through the code? We can't see any of that, so it's difficult to help with it.

Comment: I don't get any errors it takes me nowhere it stays on the old page. When I mark "./vue/episode.php" it works but it doesn't take my header into account

Comment: Well `./` would indeed just link you to the site root, and if that's the page you're already on now it might not appear to go anywhere. So what do you expect to happen due to the `action=...` parameter? Where is the code which processes that parameter and is supposed to do something with it?

Comment: Actually wait...I just looked again at your URL, and it doesn't seem to be valid. Look more closely: `href="./?action=episode?idE` ...you cannot have two `?`s in the URL, that character is used to mark the start of the query parameters. To separate two parameters you need `&`. So I think it should be `href="./?action=episode&idE...` . Try that and see if it helps. That's why I asked you if you'd verified that the URL it generates is correct...I assume you didn't take that step, or didn't look very closely at it, if you did. I just noticed it now when re-reading the code.

Comment: thank you very much you solved my problem it was href="./?action=episode&idE... and not href="./?action=episode?idE...